# Build a static site with polymer-cli

Tags: nginx, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

Ok I'm new to Polymer, after seeing the main page and Google IO 2016 video, I wanted to try it out, and right now I created a basic web application with it.

I managed to get it build and running it through the "polymer serve" command, but now that I want to release it to a production environment (I have an nginx cluster), how do I build the application to just a bunch of static website files?

I executed "polymer build" and I see the build folder and it contains 2 folders: bundled and unbundled, and inside them there are the bower_components, src and test folders as well as other stuff for running it through "polymer serve" but there's not a build/dist of build/static folder that I can copy into nginx so the application is served through it.

BTW, what I mean about a dist folder is without a readme, bower.json, test, bower_components, etc. just the pure needed HTML, CSS, JS, etc files that need to be served through nginx (or any other web server) as static file web content.

I went through [the documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) but there's no details on how to do such task.

Any suggestions on how to build a static content folder for serving my polymer web app through nginx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Polymer-CLI v0.11.0, there's no built-in way to filter out files from the bundle, but it's a [requested feature](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/241). Also, the build output currently [includes extraneous files](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/265) (a bug), such as the `test` directory.

As an alternative, you could use [Polymer Starter Kit 1.3.0](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/releases/tag/v1.3.0), whose `dist` folder doesn't include the extra files (although it does include *required* `bower_components` as-is).